# No elegir valor en estrellas al envíar datos PHP

Tags: php, html, radio

Panel de administración para el cliente de una web de reservas en el cual el cliente puede escribir y dar su opinión sobre una reserva que ha tenido lugar.

Hay un apartado para poder evaluar la estancia (seleccionando estrellas del 0-5) en cuanto a calidad, Si no marcamos nada en el valor de las estrellas, automáticamente el valor es **0.**

¿Por qué si no marco ninguna estrella me da el siguiente error?

> Notice: Undefined index: estrellas in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\daw\menu_cliente.php on line 20

Intenta coger el valor de las estrellas, pero al ser **0**, no seleccionar ninguna, no encuentra ese valor en `$_POST["estrellas"];`

1) ¿Cómo se subsanaría este error?**

2) Y además, sólo se puede enviar la opinión si el textarea no está vacío.**

**Código:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Opiniones.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Añadir opinion"...
    if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"])){
        $idemail = $cliente;
        $idcabana = $_POST["a_anadir"];
        $opinion = $_POST["texto_opinion"];
        $fecha = new DateTime();
        $fecha_hoy = $fecha->format ('Y/m/d');
        $valoracion = $_POST["estrellas"]; //Al no seleccionar nada, no coge el 0...
        BD::insertarOpinionPorReserva($idemail, $idcabana, $opinion, $fecha_hoy, $valoracion);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del cliente</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido ".$cliente."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</a></p>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_cliente">
            <ul id="menu_horizontal">
                <li><a href="menu_cliente.php?nueva=1">NUEVA OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu_cliente.php?ver=1">VER OPINIONES</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1">ELIMINAR OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=1">DATOS PERSONALES</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cuerpo_body">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el link "Nueva opinión"...
                if(isset($_GET["nueva"])){
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerReservasPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
                    $reservas = BD::obtenerReservasPorCliente($cliente);
                    echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?nueva=1' name='form_add_opinion' id='form_add_opinion' method='POST'>";
                    $selected = true;
                    foreach ($reservas as $reserva){
                        $idreserva = $reserva["idreserva"];
                        $idcabana = $reserva["idcabana"];
                        $idemail = $reserva["idemail"];
                        $check_in = new DateTime($reserva["check_in"]);
                        $check_out = new DateTime($reserva["check_out"]);
                        $reserva_toString = "Reserva de la cabaña ".$idcabana. " | ".$idemail. " | ".$check_in->format('d/m/Y'). " | ".$check_out->format('d/m/Y')."<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<input type='radio' name='a_anadir' value='".$reserva["idcabana"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$reserva_toString."</input>";
                        $selected = false;
                    }
                    echo "<br/><p class='deja_opinion'>Deja tu opinión:</p><br/>";
                    echo "<textarea rows='4' cols='56' id='texto_opinion' name='texto_opinion'></textarea><br/>";
                    echo "<p class='valoracion'>";
                        echo "<input id='radio1' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='5'>";
                        echo "<label for='radio1'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio2' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='4'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio2'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio3' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='3'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio3'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio4' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='2'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio4'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio5' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='1'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio5'>★</label>";   
                    echo "</p><br/>";

                    echo "<input type='submit' name='add_opinion' id='add_opinion' value='Añadir opinion'>";
                    echo "</form>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podría validar esto antes de asignar `$valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])?$_POST["estrellas"]: "0"`

Comment: ¿Y para validar que sólo se envíe si el textarea no está vacío? Es otra parte de la pregunta. @Dev.Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para validar el radio , simplemente podría hacer la validación empleando la sintaxis de un operador ternario.

```
$valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])?$_POST["estrellas"]: "0";
```

Para validar que se agregue un texto en la opinión , haría la misma valoración pero además teniendo en cuenta que no esté vacío el campo con [! empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

```
 if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"])){
    if(isset($_POST['texto_opinion']) && !empty($_POST['texto_opinion'])){
        $valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])?$_POST["estrellas"]: "0";
        echo "Gracias por Agregar su valoración :  " . $valoracion;
    }
    else{
        echo "Debe agregar una Opinión para agregar la valoración";
    }
}
```

> Aunque la recomendación sería validar esto directamente desde el
>   frontend , con `JavaScript` y evitar la carga de página innecesaria.

Comment: Es muy útil. Estaba amoldándola a mi código la respuesta. Entendible y útil. Ya me funciona. Te acepto la respuesta. Igual intento añadirlo con front-end desde JS con document.getElementById("texto_opinion"); con un evento onclick al pulsar el botón así no sería necesario la recarga de la página...

Comment: ¿Me recomiendas que lo haga desde el botón submit en un evento onclick o desde el form con un estilo onsubmit="return funcion();? ¿Es lo mismo verdad?

Comment: @omaza1990 prefiero la opción del evento `click` o `submit` desde `JavaScript` o `Jquery`, no tocar eventos desde el `HTML` .